# Ruined my system, how to save all firefox data?

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, firefox, backup

I have a windows 7 system dual-booted with a kubuntu bionic i broke. I will reinstall linux and i want to save all my firefox data including logins, cookies, indexeddb. Is there some folder i need to copy? I have the following limitations:

- no access to kde
- no internet connection while on linux

I can copy all files and directories I want windows so that's no issue.

tl;dr: bring all firefox data to new linux installation without gui or internet

Comment: Are you looking for the firefox cache for Windows or Kubuntu? If you're using Kubuntu, was firefox installed with `apt` or `snap`?

Comment: I'm looking for the firefox cache that's on kubuntu, it was installed with `apt`

Comment: As @MidwayNomad stated below, your profile is in `~/.mozilla`. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_working-with-profiles provides information on how to use that data, and https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile shows you how to recover data from an old profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your firefox bookmarks, cookies and passwords should be in ~/.mozilla. All of the items ***except*** your logins can be copied over and used on the new OS. The login info will be encrypted and cannot be decrypted when transferred between os'es. So, firefox will see that there is a file with the login info, but will not be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

May be too late now but for the future, if you wish to bring Firefox bookmarks to any new installation or another device then create a Firefox account.

This will allow you to sync your account across all devices.

To create an account:

```
Click the Firefox Account icon in the toolbar.
Click Sign in to Firefox.
Fill out the form to create an account. Take note of the email address and password you used. ...
Firefox Accounts will send you a confirmation email. ...
Click the Firefox Account icon to expand the menu.
Click Sync Now.
```

Follow the instructions in this support reference from Mozilla

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-sync-my-computer